# Flutter go_router: how to use ShellRoute with an expanded child?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

Given the following go_router config:

```
GoRouter(
      initialLocation: "/one",
      routes: [
        ShellRoute(
          builder: (_, __, child) => Scaffold(body: Column(children: [const Text("Header"), child],)),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              path: '/one',
              builder: (_, __) => const Expanded(child: Text("one")),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
```

the framework won't be able to render the tree due to the following error: `Assertion failed: ... hasSize`. If I understand correctly that is because `ShellRoute` wraps its child into a `Navigator` which will impose max constraints on the nested content.

How can I build a nested navigation as above where I have some fixed elements in a `Column` as part of the shell, and the child route should fill up the remaining available space vertically?

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

```
...
ShellRoute(
  builder: (_, __, child) => ScaffoldWithNavBar(child: child),
  routes: [
    ...
  ],
),
...
```

ScaffoldWithNavBar

```
class ScaffoldWithNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ScaffoldWithNavBar({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: child),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar() {
    ... 
  }
}
```

See [ShellRoute class](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html)